# Best way to "combine" functions in algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am new to programming but I have been trying my hands at an algorithm lately. I need to perform calculations with an equation that uses all angles in a structural assembly in the coordinate plane as variables. The assembly variables, so I need this function to go through the data and  combine individual equations for each two points in the assembly into the equation that is used for calculations. The part that I am confused about is how to go about combining these functions. I would like to do this in almost an "append-like" manner, if there is such a thing.

Let's say I am going through the data and at this point I have the function

```
a = lambda (x1,x2,x3,x4): (x1*x2)+(x3*x4)
```

previously generated from the first two sets, now I want to add an eq. from a third set

```
b = lambda (x5,x6): (x5/x6)

def new_lambda(a,b):
    return lambda (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6): (x1*x2)+(x3*x4)+(x5/x6)
```

This is a simple example of what I want to do. I'm not that familiar with anything beyond the basics of function creation so this may be a bit over my head. Feel free to refer me to general reading. If clarification is needed I can do that too.

Comment: You should up-vote all the answers below you thought were worthy and accept one, if any, that you feel best solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you need to know the arity of each function, in order to assign the arguments of the "combined" function accordingly.

Maybe you can wrap your functions in a class, something like this:

```
class Function:
    def __init__ (self, arity, f):
        self.arity = arity
        self.f = f

    def __call__ (self, *args):
        return self.f (*args)

    def __add__ (self, g):
        if not isinstance (g, Function):
            raise Exception ('Here be dragons')
        def fg (*args):
            return self.f (*args [:self.arity] ) + g.f (*args [self.arity:] )
        return Function (self.arity + g.arity, fg)

a = Function (4, lambda x1, x2, x3, x4: (x1 * x2) + (x3 * x4) )
b = Function (2, lambda x1, x2: x1 / x2)
print (a (1, 2, 3, 4) )
print (b (10, 20) )
c = a + b
print (c (1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20) )
```

---

Some words on inspection of the arity. The resulting function `fg` has only one argument, namely `*x` and its inspected arity will result in 0, hence prohibiting adding already added functions. Take a look here:

```
#Using my original class
a = Function (2, lambda x1, x2: x1 * x2)
b = Function (2, lambda x1, x2: x1 / x2)
c = a + a
print (c (1, 2, 3, 4) ) #prints 14
c = c + b
print (c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ) #prints 14.833333333333334
```

Now if we use inspection like this (please correct me if you intended another use of it):

```
import inspect

class InspectedFunction:
    def __init__ (self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__ (self, *args):
        return self.f (*args)

    def __add__ (self, g):
        if not isinstance (g, InspectedFunction):
            raise Exception ('Here be dragons')
        arity = len (inspect.getargspec (self.f).args) 
        def fg (*args):
            return self.f (*args [:arity] ) + g.f (*args [arity:] )
        return InspectedFunction (fg)

a = InspectedFunction (lambda x1, x2: x1 * x2)
b = InspectedFunction (lambda x1, x2: x1 / x2)
c = a + a
print (c (1, 2, 3, 4) ) #prints 14
c = c + b
print (c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ) #inspected arity of c is 0
```

will do this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nomimporta.py", line 45, in <module>
    print (c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) )
  File "nomimporta.py", line 30, in __call__
    return self.f (*args)
  File "nomimporta.py", line 37, in fg
    return self.f (*args [:arity] ) + g.f (*args [arity:] )
  File "nomimporta.py", line 37, in fg
    return self.f (*args [:arity] ) + g.f (*args [arity:] )
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: I'll second that +1 for the idea, even though I don't care much your coding style. However the implementation could be improved by removing the `arity` argument passed to `__init__()` and either using `self.arity = len(inspect.getargspec(f).args)` or even better, just get it from `self.f` when it's needed to define the nested `fg()` function.

Comment: Wow, did not know anything about creating classes, but now that I've read a bit on it, it makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: @martineau is this right?
            `def fg (*args):
                arity = len(inspect.getargspec(self.f).args)
                return self.f (*args [:arity] ) + g.f    (*args[arity:])` (I'm a little confused about how to write code in comments sorry)

Comment: @Taylor: That would work. A slightly better position for the assignment to `arity` would be up one line so it was outside of the body of the `fg()` function itself.

Comment: @martineau I fear this will fail, when you add functions repeatedly, as the resulting `fg` has as parameters `*args` and hence its calculated arity will be zero. If I am not mistaken, `c = a + b` will still work, but `d = c + c` will fail utterly.

Comment: @martineau I have edited my answer in order to reflect my concern. Maybe you could take a look at it and come up with a way to use inspect even with varargs.

Comment: @TaylorStevens Please see my last edit to my answer, before using inspection.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thank you for addressing this, I was about to say something.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: You're quite correct about `inspect.getargspec()` not working for compound combinations - which means my idea for improving your implementation it wouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I will add another answer in order not to overload my first one and because this one includes both my initial idea and the valuable input from [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) (and this time hopefully PEP-8 compliant).

Let's define a function like this and let's try to guess its arity:

```
import inspect
import operator

class UnguessableArityException(Exception): pass

class Function:
    def __init__(self, f, arity = ...):
        self.f = f
        self.arity = arity
        if arity == ...:
            argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(f)
            if argspec.varargs or argspec.kwonlyargs:
                raise UnguessableArityException()
            self.arity = len(argspec.args)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.f(*args)

    def op(self, g, op):
        if isinstance(g, Function):
            return Function(lambda *args: op(self.f(*args[:self.arity]), g.f(*args[self.arity:])), self.arity + g.arity)
        return Function(lambda *args: op(self.f(*args), g), self.arity)

    def rop(self, g, op):
        return Function(lambda *args: op(g, self.f(*args)), self.arity)

    def __add__(self, g): return self.op(g, operator.add)
    def __radd__(self, g): return self.rop(g, operator.add)
    def __mul__(self, g): return self.op(g, operator.mul)
    def __rmul__(self, g): return self.rop(g, operator.mul)
    def __truediv__(self, g): return self.op(g, operator.truediv)
    def __rtruediv__(self, g): return self.rop(g, operator.truediv)
```

Now we basically just need to define identity:

```
#define identity
i = Function(lambda x: x) # λx.x
```

And using the identity you can start to build your "growing" ("appending") functions.

```
#now you can start building your function
f = i * i # λxy.x*y
print(f(3, 2))

#later in your code you need to "append" another term λxy.x*y
f = f + f # λxyza.x*y+z*a
print(f(3,2,1,4))

#even later, you need to "append" a term λxy.x/y
f = f + i / i # λxyzabc.x*y+z*a+b/c
print(f(3,2,1,4,14,2))

#works also with constants
f = 2 * f # λxyzabc.2*(x*y+z*a+b/c)
print(f(3,2,1,4,14,2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Still trying to wrap my head around how this code works, but it does work like I need it to.

Comment: @TaylorStevens If you want join me in chat and I'll explain. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44192/best-way-to-combine-functions-in-algorithm

Comment: Again, very clever. Might want to add a class attribute `Function.i = Function(lambda x: x) # λx.x` following the class definition.

Comment: @martineau Danke für die Blumen.

Comment: If you're not saying that sarcastically, bitte schön.

Comment: @martineau No sarcasm at all. It is nice to receive peer confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a lambda for the combination? It's simple, explicit and some syntactic sugar helps with readability.

```
a = lambda x1, x2, x3, x4: (x1*x2)+(x3*x4)
b = lambda x5, x6: x5/x6
c = lambda *x: a(*x[0:4]) + b(*x[4:6])
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20)
```

For a bit more functional coding, the [functools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) module is useful. For working with collections, the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module is good to know.

Comment: Your idea isn't bad, but you obviously didn't try running the code in your answer.

Comment: @martineau: did … and then pasted an obviously old version -_- . Thanks!